# Brace initialization in arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, curly-braces

I want to know how to intialize values to some elements of array such as.

```
int arr[5]={3,5,6};
```

in a way that the index of 3 is 0 and 5 is 2.
So index 1 is skipped and automatically assigned value by compiler!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's an interesting question, why do you want to be able to do this instead of doing `int arr[5]; arr[0] = 3; arr[2] = 5;`?

Comment: That's not a thing AFAIK. Also, why?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Someone told me there is a way to do that and i am curious how? I just want to know if anyone try that so he/she could skip an element with its default value.

Comment: I have one question: why do you need an uninitialized element? Looks like you are willing to pay additional money for the less secure thing without any reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in a way that the index of 3 is 0 and 5 is 2.

That would be

```
int arr[5] = {3,0,5,6};
```

> So index 1 is skipped and automatically assigned value by compiler!

You cannot skip elements in the middle, only in the end as in your

```
int arr[5] = {3,5,6};
```

Where the missing elements in the end are initialized with 0.

Note that what you want is possible in C. Example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization):

> ```
> int n[5] = {[4]=5,[0]=1,2,3,4} // holds 1,2,3,4,5
> ```

However this is not (yet?) possible in standard C++.

**PS**: If you do not care about portability (actually you should) you can study your compilers manual to see if it allows the c-style initialization also in C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver and I removed to link to the video from the answer again. Have to watch it first. Too tired now to really get the point of it

Comment: a video about the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAdLwUXRUvg&feature=youtu.be&t=637

Comment: Thanks for your time guys! I don't think there is a way to do that as i read some books last night! Thanks anyway. If there was an answer i Wil post

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how to intialize values to some elements of array ... So index 1 is skipped

This is not possible. It is only possible to provide an initaliser to elements in order; they cannot be skipped. What you can do is initialise the array to zero, and assign some of the elements later. Example:

```
int arr[5]{};
arr[0] = 3;
arr[2] = 5;
```

or, you can use default initialisation instead:

```
int arr[5];
arr[0] = 3;
arr[2] = 5;
```

In which case the elements will have indeterminate values until assigned. Do not ever read indeterminate values; It is not useful and typically results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: By automatic it mean the compiler assigns whatever it wants automatically without our involvement.